# R read csv as character string

Tags: r, csv, character

new to R and haven't been able to locate an answer to this question. I am using the following to create a new variable that tags each line as containing a word, or not.

```
a$keywordtag <- (1:nrow(a) %in% c(sapply(needle, grep, a$text, fixed = TRUE)))
```

the 'needle' or the words to search for is being read in as:

```
needle <- c("foo", "x", "y")
```

However, I want the needle to read in as a csv file. read.csv doesn't seem to have the option to read in as a character string.  stringsAsFactors=FALSE doesn't work either. Any suggestions on this?

The csv would be:

```
 a <- read.table(text='
"foo"
"x"
"y"', header=FALSE)
```

Comment: What does the file you're trying to read look like? You can always convert using `as.character` after reading in the data.

Comment: How are you storing the data in a the raw file? A single comma-separated row? If do `scan()` might be a better import option. What exactly do you mean when you say "stringsAsFactors=FALSE doesn't work"? Because if used correctly is wont turn character into vectors. There's likely something wrong with your code that you're not showing.

Comment: Using 'read.csv' and the 'colClasses' argument will to what you are looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have all the text in one string and end each line with a new line character

```
(rc <- read.csv(text = paste0(needle, collapse = "\n"), header = FALSE))
   V1
1 foo
2   x
3   y
identical(a, rc)
# [1] TRUE
```

You could also try `readLines`

```
read.csv(text = readLines(textConnection(needle)), sep = "\n", header = FALSE)
   V1
1 foo
2   x
3   y
```

In the last line, if `needle` is actually a file, replace `textConnection(needle)` with the file name

Answer (score 3):

If stringsAsFactors=FALSE isn't working for you, you might focus on troubleshooting that.  The following code should work just fine to read in as character strings:

```
> needle = read.csv("PathToNeedle\\needle.csv", stringsAsFactors=FALSE, header=FALSE)
> needle[1]
   V1
1 foo
2   x
3   y
> typeof(needle[1,1])
[1] "character"
```

If the csv file you are reading in to needle is really just:

```
"foo"
"x"
"y"
```

then that's very peculiar.  What is the resulting dataframe you get when you run read.csv?  If it simply isn't working, an alternative to try is to directly specify the data type as follows:

```
needle = read.csv("PathToNeedle\\needle.csv", colClasses=c('character'), header=FALSE)
```

Comment: colClasses=c('character') worked for me